# How do I stop reading a file when it comes across a specific character?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I am trying to read and print a text file that looks something like this.

```
Date1
Food1-Calories1
Food2-Calories2
Food3-Calories3
*
Date2
Food1-Calories1
Food2-Calories2
Food3-Calories3
Food4-Calories4
Food5-Calories5
*
Date3
Food1-Calories1
Food2-Calories2
Food3-Calories3
Food4-Calories4
```

I am having trouble because the number of food items varies depending on how many the user enters. Therefor, I can't put a specific number of `getline()` in my code.

So I thought to add a '*' at the end of each day to let the file know to stop reading. However I don't know what condition to write in the 2nd while-loop to make it work.

Here is a sample code of what I have in mind.

```
while(inputFile.good())
{
    std::string date, foodItem, calories;

    getline(inputFile, date, '\n');

    std::cout << date << endl;

    while(the file does not read a '*')
    {
        getline(inputFile, foodItem, '-');
        getline(inputFile, calories, '\n);

        std::cout << foodItem << " " << calories;
    }

    //When a star is read, start this loop again with the next date
}

inputFile.close();
```

This is what my program looks like. But I want the foods items separated by date.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBWeD.png (I don't have enough points to post an image)

Answer (score 0):

In general the solution is pretty simple, but I would not go with "stop reading the file"

```
std::string line;
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> mainList;
std::vector<std::string> currentList;
while(getline(inputFile, line))
{
    if (line == "*") {
        mainList.push_back(currentList);
        currentList = std::vector<std::string>();
    } else {
        currentList.push_back(line);
    }
}
mainList.push_back(currentList);
inputFile.close();

// post process
```

Something like that